# Dealing with SVN merge issues

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, compare

After trying a merge through different branches, I'm facing the following problems

- Tortoise SVN sees some conflicts
- Trying to solve the conflicts by editing them shows some empty files
- There is no file marked as 'in conflict' but they contains this kind of text 
  <<<<<<< .working ======= >>>>>> .merge-right.r12532

As a solution I'd like to have an extra check through an external comparison tool but I need a way to find every file modified by the merge. Have you got suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you are looking.

File :-

1. you can do right click-> `TortoiseSVN->Diff later`.

Folder :-

1. right click the folder -> `TortoiseSVN->Repository Browse` then right click the folder and use the `Mark for comparison` option.
2. use revision graph `TortoiseSVN->Revision Graph`.

Comment: A file conflict occurs when two or more developers have changed the same few lines of a file. As Subversion knows nothing of your project, it leaves resolving the conflicts to the developers. The conflicting area in a text file is marked like this:

<<<<<<< filename
your changes
=======
code merged from repository
>>>>>>> revision

Comment: yes, but how can I interpret the data from revision graph?